# Using awk to merge two files associating numbers

Tags: awk

I have two files, note that I'd like to use the last column like a reference:

1) First file:

```
[robert@10-2Fontes]$ head rxid 
0.086297     id 0    udp    767     0
0.091866     id 1    udp    760     1
0.097236     id 2    udp    733     2
0.103616     id 3    udp    869     3
0.110956     id 4    udp    1000    4
0.459247     id 9    udp    754     54
```

Note: this file have 64196 lines.

2) Second File (reference):

```
[robert@10-2Fontes]$ head pumba.txt 
0.086297 0
0.091866 1
0.097236 2
0.103616 3
0.110956 4
0.118285 5
0.125615 6
0.130077 7
0.459247 54
```

This file is a index and have 64677 lines,

3) I would like a 3rd file, where it search the correspondent number in file 2 and put the number related in the last column of the first file. Something like that:

```
0.086297     id 0    udp    767     0 0.086297
0.091866     id 1    udp    760     1 0.091866
0.097236     id 2    udp    733     2 0.097236
0.103616     id 3    udp    869     3 0.103616
0.110956     id 4    udp    1000    4 0.110956
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}$6 in a{print $0,a[$6]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case , you can even make the first column as reference as well , then you don't need to have the last column for reference checking. I mean suppose you have

file1:

```
0.086297     id 0    udp    767     
0.091866     id 1    udp    760     
0.097236     id 2    udp    733     
0.103616     id 3    udp    869     
0.110956     id 4    udp    1000    
0.459247     id 9    udp    754
```

and file2:

```
0.086297 0
0.091866 1
0.097236 2
0.103616 3
0.110956 4
0.118285 5
0.125615 6
0.130077 7
0.459247 54
```

You can still combine them based on the first column like this

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next;}$1 in a {print a[$1]" "$2}' file1.txt file2.txt`

1. `.NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next;}` for the first file the First column will be used as index to store the whole line and next portion will be skipped
2. For the second file if `$1` first column exist in array `a` then we combine the previous saved line with the second column `$2`

Final Output

```
0.086297     id 0    udp    767 0
0.091866     id 1    udp    760 1
0.097236     id 2    udp    733 2
0.103616     id 3    udp    869 3
0.110956     id 4    udp    1000 4
0.459247     id 9    udp    754 54
```